# Checking own review quality

Tags: support, review-queues

I just hit the 2k limit and started reviewing. Lately I noticed that I confused answer and question in a single edit review that was a bit tricky (because the edited answer looked like it was a question that was answered by its author by edit).

I found that three other people fortuantely didn't make the same mistake and approved the edit as I should have done.

Now I wonder how I could check my review quality. Is there a page where I can see a list of my reviews that ended disputed (i.e. me having a different opinion than the majority of voters) so I can learn from my mistakes?

Comment: No, that is NOT a duplicate. I am not interested in *audits*. I am interested in disputed *normal reviews* (where I was the reason for the dispute).

Comment: Well, the answer is basically the same but as you insist I retracted my close vote.

Answer (score 3):

You can visit the history tab of the particular queue:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/history

With a screenshot to  clearify:

[image]

You can click each Reject / Edit or Approve [link](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6355929) to see what your peers did.

[image]

If you're interested in your overall score for suggested-edits you can use [the SEDE query in this answer of mine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187083/how-is-my-acceptance-criteria-in-suggested-edits-review-compared-with-the-comu/244665#244665)

There are some feature-requests on MSE that ask for more insight in your own review quality in releation to your peers. You could upvote those. For example [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172653/improve-reviewing-quality-by-communication-between-reviewers).

Comment: No exactly what I am looking for (since it is a pain to check the review one by one manually) but helpful.

Comment: Where can I find my UserId that is needed for that SEDE query? I tried the number shown in the URL of my profile page but it didn't return any  data.

Comment: SEDE is only updated once a week. You're not yet in the results